# Ocasional duplicate records in DSE solr even though the key is same

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax

I am running a 2 node solr cluster that indexes Cassandra database. What I have noticed is once in a while when I update record, two entry for the same record is created. This results in duplicate results when querying. This does not happen always and is only observed randomly. Difficult to reproduce but it causes the front end to appear buggy.

Here is my schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<schema name="autoSolrSchema" version="1.5">
<types>
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.StrField" name="StrField"/>
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TrieIntField" name="TrieIntField"/>
</types>
<fields>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="username" stored="true" type="StrField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="email" stored="true" type="StrField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="points" stored="true" type="TrieIntField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="true" name="city" stored="true" type="TextField"/>
</fields>
<uniqueKey>(username,email)</uniqueKey>
</schema>
```

However, after I reload core, the duplicate entries are removed.

**UPDATED:**

I have uploaded the solrconfig here:
[SolrConfig.xml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0HE5pp8hcd9Tkx2ekxCeGZ4ZHM/view?usp=sharing)

Here is the CQL Table:

```
CREATE TABLE smartcity.users (
username text,
email text,
city list,
points int,
solr_query text,
PRIMARY KEY (username, email)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (email ASC) AND
bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
comment='' AND
dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
replicate_on_write='true' AND
populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
compression={'sstable_compression': 'LZ4Compressor'};
```

Comment: I am using DSE 4.6.4

Comment: Mmmm not seen this in 4.6 beofre. I'd be very insterested in trying to repro. Could you provide exact cql table, schema (if not the above one), solrconfig and some indication of size and steps to repro please?

Comment: I have added the solrconfig.xml and the CQL table. It happens once in a while when I update a record via solr. But when I reload, its all ok.